# How to limit UI in a web scene on ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online, html, story-map, web-scene, user-interface

I have a web scene created and on ArcGIS Online, however, there are a lot of things that the UI shows that I don't need. I am ultimately bringing this into a story map, and I have figured out how to reduce the UI by adding "&ui=min" to the end of the URL when embedding it, but doing so reduces the UI too much. I want a way to pick what UI is displayed and what UI is removed. Does anyone know how to do this in a web scene for story map purposes?

I would imagine that it can be limited in HTML to some degree, but how would I go about making that a permanent change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no way to pick specific UI tools you would want to display in an embedded scene. This is something we are planning for a future update to the web scene viewer.

Comment: Is there some way that the web scene code could be changed to exclude the header section, and then shared with full UI?

Comment: Currently this is not an option but moving forward the web apps, story maps will be gaining stronger 3D support and I will bring up the requirement to be able to customize embedded web scenes more then min UI

Comment: Thank you very much. I look forward to seeing what the future has in store for web scenes.